# scaling issue when projecting uiview in front of scenekit camera

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, 360-virtual-reality

**content**

- first i have a 360 (equirectangular) image viewer by applying the image as a texture onto a sphere with the scenekit camera at the center.
- then i enter a "drawing mode" where i can use my finger to draw on a transparent UIView
- when i'm done, i take the drawing and apply it to my sphere as an annotation

**problem (with video example)**

the problem is in this 3rd step, the scale isn't saved correctly.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/a2l3vvx92sa3cgh/drawing_defect_trimmed_480p.mp4?dl=0

**temporary solution**
i was able to add a magic number to the expected scale which lessens the scaling problem, but it is still a little bit off and obviously suboptimal from a technical perspective.

e.g. “scale_used = expected_scale + magic_constant”

**implementation details**

- I am projecting a UIView in front of a Scene Kit camera at some custom
  distance in the Scene Kit world and trying to make it so the new
  Scene Kit node will have exactly the same visual size.
- the approach is to calculate the perspective projection of the item,
  located in the world at drawingContentItem.distance using camera
  zNear - “(screenHeight * distance / Float(zNear))”.
- Then we assume that size of visible world of scene kit is from -1000
  to 1000; and the view angle is 60 degrees; and calculate the ratio of
  scene Kit near plane view to UIView - “(sceneScreenHeight /
  nearPlaneHeightInWorlCoordinates)”.
- that gives us the finalHeight of drawing in the world coordinates and
  we use this to calculate the scale.
- But it seems that there is some mistake in the formula and it causes
  the need for the magical number. :(